# running dependencies with npm not working (event.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event)

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently just started getting back into web development and I had Node.js already installed on my computer. I was trying to run `npm install -g live-server` to work with npm's live server.

This is what was returned when i ran `npm install -g live-server`.

```
ashle@DESKTOP-PFHHR2C MINGW64 ~/Desktop/npmtest
$ npm install -g live-server
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
C:\Users\ashle\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server -> C:\Users\ashle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\live-server\live-server.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\live-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ live-server@1.2.1
added 191 packages from 149 contributors in 22.221s
```

The install seemed to work fine; however, when I ran `live-server` I got the following error:

```
ashle@DESKTOP-PFHHR2C MINGW64 ~/Desktop/npmtest
$ live-server
Serving "C:\Users\ashle\Desktop\npmtest" at http://127.0.0.1:8080
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I've already tried removing Node.js completely from Windows using this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) as a guide; however, once I installed node and the live server again, it still returned the same error.

I've checked the PATH to make sure C:\Users\Webmaster\AppData\Roaming\npm was in there. Maybe something went wrong there as I accidentally deleted all the other environment variables or maybe I'm completely oblivious to something I'm doing wrong? Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Edit: I also tried installing gulp. Said packages were installed then when I tried to run it, the same message popped up, so I don't think its an issue exclusive to the live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the environment variables.

Since I accidentally cleared everything had to add back `C:\Windows\System32\` to the path and then restart. Live server works now.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85